# Trying to put images side by side with \begin{subfigure} but it's not working

Tags: graphics, subfloats

I'm trying to put two images beside each other using `subfigure` but they keep compiling on top of one another. On top of that, it's putting a "0.5" below each image and I'm not sure why. I pretty much copy-pasted the code from the overleaf page on formatting images (and inserted my own files) because the code I wrote also wasn't working. But this isn't working either. Here's the code:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
    \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth, height=6cm]{part a.png} 
        \caption{orthonormal basis $\mathcal{U}_a$}
        \label{fig:subim1}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth, height=6cm]{part b.png}
        \caption{orthonormal basis $\mathcal{U}_b$}
        \label{fig:subim2}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
```

The errors I'm getting are "Missing number, treated as zero" and "Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted)", and I'm getting two of each, one for each image. If anyone could help me out I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Erors are not caused by your code ragment. For positioning figure Use option ` ht`, reduce `subfigure` width to `0.48` and increase images width to `\linewidth`. Thos should put both sub figures in one line.

Answer (score 1):

The error message the OP reports indicates that the obsolete and deprecated `subfigure` package is being employed, instead of the much more recent `subcaption` package.

Here's the output of a minimally compilable example that builds on the OP's code and employs the `subcaption` package. (Note that I didn't add an overall `\caption` directive -- something that would ordinarily be expected in a figure/subfigure setting.)

[image]

```
\documentclass[demo]{article} % remove 'demo' option in real doc.
\usepackage{graphicx}   % for '\includegraphics' macro
\usepackage{subcaption} % for 'subfigure' environment

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \begin{subfigure}{0.475\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth, height=6cm]{part a} % no need to append '.png' 
      \caption{orthonormal basis $\mathcal{U}_a$}
      \label{fig:subim1}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \hspace{\fill}
    \begin{subfigure}{0.475\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth, height=6cm]{part b}
      \caption{orthonormal basis $\mathcal{U}_b$}
      \label{fig:subim2}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```